# ViewController properties not initialized when accessing from outside viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

My DetailViewController has a MapView on it's nib, but whenever I try to access that property in a different viewcontroller before I push it onto the navigation controller stack, I'm getting that the property is still nil, so nothing happens. Does anyone know why this might be happening? This also happens to me with UIImageViews, it's not only mapviews. (Xcode 5, ios7)

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation = [[AppDelegate sharedLocationManager] location].coordinate;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
[dvc.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

MomentAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MomentAnnotation alloc] init];
myAnnotation.coordinate = zoomLocation;
myAnnotation.title = @"Photo";
[dvc.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 view loads bit late in the memory, or we can say ViewDidLoad methods call bit latter. So when you try to set UI properties it is possibility that you get them nil. So better will be you set value after confirming that view elements are ready. presentViewController method gives completion handler where you can set values of properties. [dvc view] call this method before setting properties. This will load view in memory if it is not. And another way is set properties after pushing view controller